# Comparar dos arreglos jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenos días estoy iterando unos registros a través de AJAX, además tengo otra tabla que me trae mis favoritos, donde guardo el id del registro que tengo el like de la primera iteración.

Entonces en mi success primero itero todas las propiedades:

```
resultado.viviendas.forEach(function(vivienda) {
    //Aquí con append imprimo el html
    ....
    ....
    //luego itero la segunda tabla para obtener que ids tengo en común con la primera tabla
    resultado.likes.forEach(function(likes) {
         if(vivienda.id = likes){
           $('.cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'').html('<a class="disLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="far fa-heart" style="color: red"></i></a>');
         }else{
           $('.cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'').html('<a class="darLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>');
        }
    });
});
```

**Esto es lo que recibo con el ajax**

```
{viviendas: Array(21), likes: Array(2)}
likes: (2) [448, 402]
viviendas: (21) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Entonces lo que comparo es que si en la iteración está esa id, le pongo un corazón rojo, si no esta le pongo un corazón blanco.

Tal como esta ahora me imprime solo los corazones rojos de forma correcta, pero si el `if` lo pongo así `if(vivienda.id == likes){` me pone todos los corazones blancos menos el último que hay rojo, es decir solo saca el último rojo.

---

Enlace a [JSFiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbfast/uwbja792/)

---

**Código para actualizar corazón de blanco a rojo y viceversar**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.darLike', function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
        console.log(post_id);
        let url = '/darLike/';
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "put",
            url: url,
            data: {
                'post_id' : post_id,
                'user_id' : user_id
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#cuore_"+ post_id +"").load(location.href + " #cuore_"+ post_id +"");
            }
        });         
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.disLike', function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
        let url = '/disLike/';
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "get",
            url: url,
            data: {
                'post_id' : post_id,
                'user_id' : user_id
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#cuore_"+ post_id +"").load(location.href + " #cuore_"+ post_id +"");
            }
        });         
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te sobra el segundo foreach, yo lo haría así:

```javascript
resultado.viviendas.forEach(vivienda => 
  let tieneLike = resultado.likes.some(idLike => idLike === vivienda.id);
  if (tieneLike) {
     //añado vivienda con corazon rojo
  else {
    //añado vivienda con corazon blanco
  }
})
```

La función `array.some(funcCondicion)` devuelve `true` si alguno de los elementos del array hace que la función que le pasas devuelve true. Por ejemplo:

```js
const esPar = elem => elem % 2 === 0;

console.log('Alguno es par?',[1,2,3].some(esPar)); // el 2 es par
console.log('Alguno es par?',[1,5,3].some(esPar)); //ninguno
```

El problema de tu código es que intentas algo como

```
Para cada vivienda
  imprimo la vivienda
  Para cada like
    si coincide con el id la vivienda
       imprimo corazón rojo
    en otro caso
       imprimo corazón blanco
  fin para
fin para
```

Y es que si tienes 20 viviendas y 6 likes, para cada vivienda te va a poner 6 veces un corazón, blanco o rojo. Además, será el último comprobado el que veas en pantalla:

```js
const resultado = {
  viviendas: [
    {nombre: "A", id: 0},
    {nombre: "B", id: 1},
    {nombre: "C", id: 2},
    {nombre: "D", id: 3},
    {nombre: "E", id: 4},
    {nombre: "F", id: 5},
  ],
  likes: [1,2,5]
}

let listado = document.querySelector("#listado");
resultado.viviendas.forEach(vivienda => {
   const item = document.createElement("div");
   item.id = "v" + vivienda.id;
   const texto = "Vivienda " + vivienda.nombre;
   listado.appendChild(item);
  // ERROR: ¡con este bucle sólo se pone rojo el corazón si el último like coincide con el id!
   resultado.likes.forEach(like => {
     if (like === vivienda.id) {
       console.log("añado rojo");
       item.innerHTML = texto + " rojo";
     } else {
       console.log("añado blanco");
       item.innerHTML = texto + " blanco";
     }
   })
})
```

```css
section {
  overflow : auto;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="listado">

</section>
```

Del modo que comento sería algo como:

```js
const resultado = {
  viviendas: [
    {nombre: "A", id: 0},
    {nombre: "B", id: 1},
    {nombre: "C", id: 2},
    {nombre: "D", id: 3},
    {nombre: "E", id: 4},
    {nombre: "F", id: 5},
  ],
  likes: [1,2,5]
}

let listado = document.querySelector("#listado");
resultado.viviendas.forEach(vivienda => {
   const item = document.createElement("div");
   item.id = "v" + vivienda.id;
   const texto = "Vivienda " + vivienda.nombre;
   listado.appendChild(item);
   const tieneLike = resultado.likes.some(like => like === vivienda.id);
   if (tieneLike) {
     console.log("añado rojo");
     item.innerHTML = texto + " rojo";
   } else {
     console.log("añado blanco");
     item.innerHTML = texto + " blanco";
   }
})
```

```css
section {
  overflow : auto;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="listado">

</section>
```

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano gracias por tu respuesta, funciona perfecto, pero ahora no me va el que actualice el corazón cuando le pulso, voy a poner el código al final de mi pregunta por si me puedes asesorar. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Hola Miguel a primera vista el error es el **=** (igual) debe ser **==** en el `if(vivienda.id == likes)` y prueba utilizando otra variable porque ambas se llaman likes usa `resultado.likes.forEach(function(like)`:

```
resultado.viviendas.forEach(function(vivienda) {
    //Aquí con append imprimo el html
    ....
    ....
    //luego itero la segunda tabla para obtener que ids tengo en común con la primera tabla
    resultado.likes.forEach(function(like) {
         if(vivienda.id == like){
           $('.cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'').html('<a class="disLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="far fa-heart" style="color: red"></i></a>');
         }else{
           $('.cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'').html('<a class="darLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>');
        }
    });
});
```

puedes corregir eso a ver si funciona sino muestra un poco mas del codigo para poder ayudarte, Saludos.

AÑADO LA PRUEBA

HTML:

```
<button class="btn-Wa" id="pintaCorazones" type="button">Pinta Corazones</button>
    <div id="ConteinerCorazones"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="caso5.js"></script>
```

JS: caso5.js

```
var pinta = document.querySelector('#pintaCorazones');
pinta.addEventListener('click', PintaCorazones);
function PintaCorazones(){
    var viviendas =[{"id":402},{"id":448},{"id":400},{"id":354},{"id":250}];
    var likes =[448,402] 
    var corazones = "";
    viviendas.forEach(function(vivienda) {        
        likes.forEach(function(like) {
             if(vivienda.id == like){
               corazones = corazones+'<a class="disLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="bi bi-heart" style="color: red"></i></a>';
             }else{
                corazones = corazones+'<a class="darLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="bi bi-heart"></i></a>';
            }
        });
    });

    if(corazones != ""){
        var div = document.querySelector('#ConteinerCorazones');
        div.innerHTML= corazones;
    }
}
```

RESULTADO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @FrankLopez , he cambiado lo que me dices pero sigue sucediendo igual, que necesitas ver de código?? ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: Miguel primero , no veo nada del Html, se ve que utilizas una clase dinámica que cambia según el id y le incrustas un <a> con html pero solo muestras el js, he probado el js y si funciona.

Comment: Hola @FrankLopez , no puse el HTML por que es muy grande. ¿Que puedo hacer para ve que falla?

Comment: edite el lo que hice para que veas como lo probé y si me dio el resultado

Comment: Te voy a pegar el código en un jsfflet @FrankLopez , para no llenar mucho esto, ya veo que tu ejemplo funciona, no entiendo por que el mio no

Comment: Ya te he puesto el enlace al final de mi pregunta, perdona por que no se tabula bien el código ahí, es mucho código. Haber si me ayudas a localizar el error @FrankLopez

Comment: Pueder probar cambiando `<span class="cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'"></span>`  por  `<span id="cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'"></span>`  y en ves de  `$('.cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'').html('<a class="disLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="far fa-heart" style="color: red"></i></a>');` lo cambias por esto : `$('#cuore_'+ vivienda.id +'').append( '<a class="disLike entrie_'+ vivienda.id +' posCora" data-id="'+ vivienda.id +'" id="'+ vivienda.id +'"><i class="far fa-heart" style="color: red"></i></a>');`

Comment: Hola de nuevo @FrankLopez , nada tampoco funciona, sigue pasando lo mismo, y lo malo del `append` es que me pone un corazón encima de otro